# Angular2 cannot grab data from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, localhost, angular

I have NodeJS as backend serving up JSON data from MySQL via localhost:3002/visit; I want to have Angular2 grab the JSON from my NodeJS.
The problem is while my Angular2 app can grab JSON from online JSON API service perfectly fine, it gives error at the subscribe when I switch the URL GET to localhost:3002/visit.

NodeJS:

```
var mysql  = require('mysql');
var express  = require('express');

var app = express();
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'angela',
  database : 'emergency',
});

connection.connect(function(err){
if(!err) {
    console.log("Database is connected ... nn");    
} else {
    console.log("Error connecting database ... nn");    
}
});

app.get('/patient',getAllFromPatient);
app.get('/staff', getAllFromStaff);
app.get('/visit', getAllFromVisit);

function getAllFromPatient(req,res){
    connection.query('SELECT * from patient', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err)
        res.send(rows);
    else
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
});}

function getAllFromStaff(req,res){
    connection.query('SELECT * from staff', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err)
        res.send(rows);
    else
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
});}

function getAllFromVisit(req,res){
    connection.query('SELECT * from visit', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err){
        res.send(rows);
        console.log("visit data sent");
      }else
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
});}

app.listen(3002);
```

Angular 2:

```
return this.http.get("http://localhost:3002/visit")
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(
        data => this.msg = JSON.stringify(data),
        err => alert(err),
        () => console.log("complete")
    );
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the "error"?

Comment: Just a wild guess - have you tried using Response's `json()` method instead of `send()`?

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 needs to know that the received content is a JSON one. So the `Content-Type` header with the `application/json` value must be present in the response headers in this case.

To do that you need either to:

- Set manually the `Content-Type` header:

  ```
  function getAllFromVisit(req,res){
    connection.query('SELECT * from visit', function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (!err){
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        res.send(rows);
        console.log("visit data sent");
      }else
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
    });
  }
  ```
- Use the `json` method instead that does the same thing:

  ```
  function getAllFromVisit(req,res){
    connection.query('SELECT * from visit', function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (!err){
        res.json(rows);
        console.log("visit data sent");
      }else
        console.log('Error while performing Query.');
    });
  }
  ```